# High performance webserver design

Tags: database, apache, filesystems, couchdb

Simple form of the question first:
For serving large number of static content to a large number of clients, is it better to make an http server serve the content from the filesystem where each of the primary keys are stored in a file (Inodes!) or to implement a "real" database? With "better" I mean in terms of performance, machine load, memory usage and so on.

More detailed version of the question:
We're currently doing a redesign of a database server that has the following requirements:

- SSL
- thousands of clients (1-30.000)
- client requests are serialized, one at a time, about 100 entries within 2 min
- clients will disconnect after timeout
- some clients will later reconnect and do some more (1-10) requests
- database will contain > 100.000 primary keys
- database content is static (more or less)
- request size is usually < 80 bytes
- response size is usually  < 30 bytes

Although our protocol is currently not http I thought about using Apache or another http server and altering our protocol to fit into http. But then the next question is whether to use a "real" database (e.g. couchdb) or if we just use the filesystem as database since > 95% of the requests will be request for static content. Performance and scaling is an issue here. If e.g. 1.000 clients will be powered on at exactly 08:00 AM, it might happen that these 1.000 machines connect simultaneously and do their 100 requests each. All within two minutes, all with the overhead of establishing a ssl connection. That could bring any server to its limits.

Any hints?

Comment: If 95% of requests will be for static content, how about using a caching proxy such as http://www.squid-cache.org/ ?

Comment: Since the static content is less, it is better to cache and serve. You could check nginx also. If number of files is smaller, better is to go for Caching solutions.

Comment: Do you want to host this yourself? If you have usage spikes like the one you described, a DBaaS solution might be better.

Answer (score 1):

- As the data behind the primary keys are small (some Bytes), filesystem will not be an efficient solution, consider using some caching system as Redis as a database.
- Nginx as webserver seems more suitable to your needs than apache (small requests, and much people)
- If all your data (~100B * 100k ~ 10MB ?) fit into memory, and there is no big calculation, you should not encounter hard performance issues.